# SQL Compact Edition database corruption

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce

Our product is using MS SQL Compact Edition on a Windows machine (laptop). It's basically a metadata index for files we have on the filesystem. Recently we have seen databases getting corrupted.

This happens when the machine is very busy moving files around and has to do a tiny bit of database changes at the same time.

I was somewhat shocked that was at all possible. It was my expectation that the database would stay coherent whatever the circumstances.

Of course we are doing something wrong. Things we have checked so far are:

- Use of only one db connection per thread
- specify the maximum size when opening the database

The database is accessed only by one application, a .net based windows service. Are there other gotcha's?

Comment: By "corruption" do you mean random gibberish in place of your records, or the database otherwise being unable to be read; or do you mean the database is left in an inconsistent state (but is readable, albeit the data is incorrect)?

Comment: @Kyralessa: The database can not be opened anymore.

Comment: What version of SqlCe are you using?

Comment: @jdv: Might want to look over this great article on Private deploy - just to make sure Windows Update doesn't upgrade your End User's version of SQL CE: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQLCEPrivateInstallation.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider adding the flush interval property to your [SqlCeConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection.connectionstring.aspx) object's connection string. From MSDN:

> flush interval-or-ssce:flush interval
>   -> Specified the interval time (in seconds) before all committed
>   transactions are flushed to disk. If
>   not specified, the default value is
>   10.

You may also want to consider creating code to attempt to [repair your database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine.repair.aspx). No guarantees, but worth a try.

Comment: Thanks, I will check these out.

Comment: We'll never know the cause of the original problem, but thanks for sharing your tips.